# CURL Request Failure retry method

Tags: c++, curl

I am using CURL library for POST, GET, download and upload data. For some reason if request fails then we planned to retry the request again. we planned to retry for 5 times, even then fails then we stop and display failure message to user. For this we are running this in loop with delay of 10 second.

My question.

1) Is my approach to this is correct.

2) what is the best practice.

**UPDATE:**

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    int nRetryCount = 0;
    do 
    {
        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT); 

        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if(curl) 
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/");

            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

            if(CURLE_OK == res) 
            {
                break;
            }

            nRetryCount++;

            if (nRetryCount < 5)
            {
                //wait for 10 sec.
                Sleep(10000);
            }       
        }
    } while (nRetryCount < 5);


    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any code to back up this question? Have you tried your approach out yet?

Comment: what happens if it doesn't work after 5 times? People will always ask you why did you pick 5? is the choice Random?.I don't really like these solutions. I actually have the same problem as yours. I think that at first you need to set `nRetryCount` to the maximum say 200 or 300. Then after a certain number of runs u'll be able to guess which is the best number for `nRetryCount` . Perhaps it takes around 20 to 30 retries to be able to connect.

Answer (score 1):

You've better to check http-status-code.

```
curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE, &http_status);
if (http_status == ...) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: ok. thanks for u r input. if it fails, the way i am retrying is proper?

Comment: I'm thinking you are ok to use do-loop for retying. But I guess you should retry just only the time that you are possible to do.